Heating effect on superconductors
The formula to find the heating effect or heating energy is:-
$$H=I^2 R \Delta t$$
So, accordingly superconductors do not have any heating effect as $R=0$
But, I want to ask if this formula holds true for even superconductors or not?
This is known as the core heating. Are there other forms of heat generation in superconductor? If so, how do we calculate them.
Edit:- Wikipedia says that there is a heating effect. Is there a formula to find the amount of heating?

Does the Wikipedia article suitably address your question? (That is, dissipative mechanisms associated with Joule heating are absent at DC but not necessarily at AC.) If not, what remains unclear?

Yes, it did gave me an idea  but it also means that there is an heating effect.

Google Scholar is useful for a search for "joule heating" "superconductor" regarding current consensus on dissipative processes involving vortices, magnetic fields, large currents, etc.

Your question is a bit too vague for us to give the answer you're looking for, I think. If you have a type-I superconductor (or a type-II superconductor in low magnetic field) then you can pass a DC current through it without generating any heat (in the superconductor, at least). Under other conditions this may or may not be true, and so no, there is not a one-line equation which tells you the degree of heating in all superconductors and in all circumstances.
I would recommend trying to formulate a specific experimental setup and then asking if, in those conditions, you will have any heat generated by the current passing through your superconductor. This is a good exercise for you, because it forces you to put abstract concepts into a physical framework, and its good for us, because we can give specific answers.

Thanks, I will try to do one.
